# Is this an asian hornet

Tags: zoology, entomology

My mother found a hornet at home (in northern France) that is probably building a nest. Is that an asian hornet? If yes, how can I exterminate them?

[image]

Comment: I am not very good at species ID but it does not look like a Asian giant hornet to me. Asian giant hornets typically have wider dark stripes. It could be a European hornet. Where was the picture taken?

Comment: Yes, northern France to be precise

Comment: The OP is probably asking about the [asian hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_hornet) (which is invasive in France) rather than the asian giant hornet (which is not), though this one looks like neither.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the invasive asian hornet

Answer (score 6):

This is not a hornet, this a wasp. See the yellow dots on the thorax ? They are typical of the *Vespula* genus. So is the yellow and black stripe pattern on the abdomen. Those wasps are smaller than hornets (1-2 cm for wasps, 3-4 cm for hornets). [Picture from Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu%C3%AApe_germanique):
[image: Vespula germanica (from Wikipedia)]

There are two common *Vespula* species in France  (*V. vulgaris* and *V. germanica*), but to identify yours, we would need a better view of [the head and abdomen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespula_vulgaris).

On the image below, you can compare it to the two hornet species you can find in France ([source](https://lerucherdesplaisirs.jimdo.com/2016/11/11/identifier-abeille-gu%C3%AApe-frelon-europ%C3%A9en-ou-asiatique-ainsi-que-leurs-nids/)). The first one is a bee, the second one is a wasp (*Vespula*), the third one is the invasive "Asian hornet" (*Vespa velutina*) and the fourth one is the native "European hornet" (*Vespa crabro*).

[image: Comparison of some hymenoptera found in France (Le Rucher des Plaisirs)]

So no extermination needed ;) You can find more information (in French) on how to recognize these species on the [Natural History Museum website](http://frelonasiatique.mnhn.fr/identification/).

Sources:

- [Le Rucher des Plaisirs - French beekeeper website](https://lerucherdesplaisirs.jimdo.com/2016/11/11/identifier-abeille-gu%C3%AApe-frelon-europ%C3%A9en-ou-asiatique-ainsi-que-leurs-nids/)
- [Natural History Museum - hornet and wasp identification in France](http://frelonasiatique.mnhn.fr/identification/)
- [Same source in English](http://frelonasiatique.mnhn.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2015/07/Vespa_velutina_Identification_Sheet_MNHN.pdf)
- [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespula_vulgaris)